# OpenERP: How to override an inherited view's action?

Tags: odoo

I'd like to supress the display of the Stock Value Variation chart on the default view of the Manufacturing page. I'm using inheritance to modify the form. Right now I can inherit the form and get additional actions to show up. However, I'm not able to use position="replace" for an action, form, or on the "arch" field. So how do I stop display of the Stock Value Variation, or the other graphs?

Background: 
I'm new to OpenERP, and I'm trying to use the Manufacturing module to create a custom app for tracking prototype hardware development. Much of the functionality I want is already there, so OpenERP is a natural fit. However, the first step is to disable anything unnecessary. Inheriting and replacing *fields* to stop them from showing up hasn't been a problem, but I'm not having any luck getting rid of the *actions* that create reports and graphs.

Related questions:

- Would it be better to leave the Manufacturing pages alone, and create
  a whole new "Prototypes" module? In other words, right now I'm trying
  to change the behavior of the Manufacturing pages -- would it be
  better to create a new module and add a "Prototypes" button along
  with  Sales/Purchase/Warehouse/Manufacturing/Accounting/Settings at
  the top of the default page?
- I'm not sure where the extra "Change Layout" button at the top of the
  default Manufacturing page is comming from, or how to get rid of
  that. Any ideas?
- Is the problem I'm having derived from the dynamic names and refering
  to them in another module? (E.g. the
  name="%(procurement.procurement_exceptions)d" in mrp_boot_view.xml).

OpenERP 6.1 on Windows, install everything locally.

Here's the code:

```
__openerp__.py:

{
    "name" : "prototyping tool",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "author" : "",
    "website" : "",
    "category" : "Manufacturing",
    "sequence": 19,
    "images" : [],
    "depends" : ["mrp", "base"],
    "description": """initial version doesn't do much, simplifies MRP views.""",
    'init_xml': [],
    'update_xml': ["mrp_boot_view.xml"],
    'demo_xml': [],
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'certificate': '',
}
```

---

```
__init__.py:
    import mrp_boot
    import mrp
```

---

```
mrp_boot.py:

# None of this functionality is currently used

import mrp_boot
import mrp

from osv import fields, osv

class mrp_boot(osv.osv):
   _name = "mrp_boot"
   _inherit = "purchase.order"

   def _get_boot_expense_category(self, cursor, user_id, context=None):
       return (
           ('NRE', 'NRE'),
           ('MatProto', 'Materials / Prototype'),
           ('Capital', 'Capital'),
           ('Loaner', 'Loaner'))

   _columns = {
       'boot_expense_category':
           fields.selection( _get_boot_expense_category
                           , 'Expense Category'
                           , help="How the equipment for the entire PO is to be expensed. If multiple methods will be used, multiple POs must be created"),
       }

mrp_boot()
```

---

```
mrp_boot_view.xml:

# I'd like to supress the display of the charts generated by the actions 
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<openerp>
<data>
     <record id="board_mrp_manager_form" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">board.mrp.manager.form</field>
          <field name="model">board.board</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.board_mrp_manager_form" />
          <field name="type">form</field>
          <field name="priority" eval="15"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">

               <form string="Manufacturing board">
                    <board style="2-1">
                        <column>
                            <action name="%(procurement.procurement_exceptions)d" string="New Prototype Outlook" domain="[('state','=','exception')]"/>
                        </column>
                        <column>
                        </column>
                    </board>
                </form>

          </field>
     </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use replace attribute to modify anything in action.

To inherit action or make changes in action you can override action's id.

For Example I want to override action of procurement module, then I can change view_type or view_mode or context or search_view_id as per my requirement:

```
<record id="procurement.procurement_exceptions" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Procurement Exceptions</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">procurement.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_perm_exceptions':1}</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="procurement.view_procurement_filter"/>
</record>
```

To remove extra stuff from inherited view (taken from comment):

```
<record id="my_customized_board_mrp_manager_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">board.mrp.manager.form</field>
    <field name="model">board.board</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.board_mrp_manager_form" />
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <action name="%(mrp.action_report_in_out_picking_tree)d" position="replace"/>
    </field>
<record>
```

Comment: Thanks you -- that helps a lot. This lets me replace fields, which is a step in the right direction. However, still I'm not sure how to get rid of, for example, the Stock Value Variation  chart on the Manufacturing landing page. I'd like to remove it on an inherited view page, without editing the parent's source code. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course you can do so by inherit that view in your customized module.

Here is the code:
    <record id="my_customized_board_mrp_manager_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">board.mrp.manager.form</field>
            <field name="model">board.board</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.board_mrp_manager_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <action name="%(mrp.action_report_in_out_picking_tree)d" position="replace"/>
     </field>
<record>

Comment: I keep getting errors about the XML format. I can get this to work: <record id="my_customized_board_mrp_manager_form" model="ir.ui.view"> <field name="name">board.mrp.manager.form</field> <field name="model">board.board</field> <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.board_mrp_manager_form" /> <field name="type">form</field> <field name="arch" type="xml"> <action name="%(mrp.action_report_in_out_picking_tree)d" string="replace"/> </field> </record> -- note the action has *string="replace"* not *position="replace*. Change it to position="replace" and re-import I get an error.

Comment: The best solution so far: Go to: Settings -> Customization -> User Interface -> Views. Search for Object = board and then edit the entry for: board.mrp.manager.form

Comment: I forgot to say that you need to add all the necessary access rights in Settings -> Users -> Users, or you won't see all  the menus for Settings -> Customization -> User Interface -> Views.

Comment: @JeffP.: answers should go in answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inheriting all fields from purchase.order there is no need for you to use _name='mrp_boot' .. Because you are using an existing object ,not creating a new object